# Calling functions in JS library from vuejs application

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2

I'm trying to import a js library implemented in api.js like this:

```
var api = (function() {

    function _logon() {
        return "You logged on";
    }

    return {
        logon: _logon
    };

}());
```

Within my vue file script tags I've tried:

```
    import * as api from '../api.js'
    //and
    import api from '../api.js'

    export default {
        name: "Logon",
        created(){
          var res =  api.logon();
        }
  }
  //Error in created hook: "TypeError: _api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.logon is not a function"
```

I'm unable to modify the js library, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You need to use module.exports in your api.js file

Answer (score 1):

1. create a file name api.js :

   ```
   function login() {
      return 'You logged on';
   }

   function logout() {
      return 'Logout!';
   }
   export default {
     login,
     logout
   }
   ```

2- import from file.vue file

```
  import api from './../api'

  export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
     msg: String
  },
  mounted() {
    let restul = api.login();
    console.log(restul);

    console.log(api.login());
  }
 }
```